# Modify Unity's New 2D Renderer for the Lighweight Render Pipeline

Tags: unity, 2d, shaders, rendering

I would like to use the new 2D renderer available with the *LWRP* to take advantage of the 2D lights.

I would also like to replicate the things [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szsWx9IQVDI) - basically, I want my character to be visible through walls and when it is occluded.

The video uses the Forward Renderer to add the depth features, but there is no such thing in the properties of the 2D Renderer. Is it possible to both use the new 2D lights and use renderer features?